# Number of objects eligible for garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am not sure if I have understood the behaviour of garbage collector completely, therefore I am posing this question based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299604/interview-question-objects-eligible-for-garbage-collection?rq=1).

In this program:

```
class A {
    Boolean b;
    A easyMethod(A a){
       return new A();
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new A();
        A a3 = new A();
        a3 = a1.easyMethod(a2);
        a1 = null;
        // Some other code 
    }
}
```

how many objects would be eligible for garbage collection? I think that although `a3` never becomes null, the first object (`new A()`) assigned to it should also be garbage-collected, as no references still point to it. Am I right? I think hence that the correct answer would be again 2 objects. What is true actually?

Comment: Don't base your question on another question, this is not a discussion thread. Post the complete code of relevance here.

Comment: The compiler may well discard any variables and assignments which it finds will never be read again during their potential lifetime. So, an object assigned to a variable in your code is not automatically referenced, or 'reachable', thereafter at runtime, which means that the object may be eligible for collection immediately after its constructor was executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that although `a3` never becomes null, the first object (`new A()`) assigned to it should also be garbage-collected, as no references still point to it. Am I right? I think hence that the correct answer would be again 2 objects.

Yes, this is exactly right. `a3` originally points to one instance of `A`, but after that variable is reassigned to point to a different instance, there is no longer any way to reach the original instance, so said original instance becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.

```
a1 = <instance 1>
a2 = <instance 2>
a3 = <instance 3>
a3 = <instance 4> //as a returned value
a1 = null
```

So `instance 1` and `instance 3` are no longer referenced and thus may be collected.