# Which object(s) is/are eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Saw this question somewhere, and it makes me confused about the gc concept. So when it comes to line

```
s2 = null;
```

Which object is eligible for gc? I think s1 should be the eligible one. What do you think?

Following are the code. Please forgive me about any issue of the format as I'm using mobile.

```
class Student {
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

And

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Student s1 = new Student();
        Student s2 = new Student();
        Student s3 = new Student();

        s1 = s3;
        s3 = s2;
        s2 = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: When the `main()` method ends, all three variables will be garbage collected.  Also, had you extended your code in `main()` further, some variables could also have become eligible for GC if they were no longer being used/referenced.

Comment: The only line that makes an object lose all references to it is `s1 = s3;`. The rest of the objects become eligible for GC from just going out of scope.

Comment: @4castle From the method exiting. There is no 'going out of scope' instruction in the bytecode.

Comment: @EJP: the implications of local variables having no scope, is, that the JVM may consider them non-existent at any time, if not subsequently read. If the optimizer were active in this short program, all objects were eligible for gc *at any time*, if they were ever created. I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14171110/2711488) nails it…